# angularjs nggrid table title with date format

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I noticed that when using nggrid, if the data looks like this:

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", '2004-08-17': 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", '2004-08-17': 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", '2004-08-17': 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", '2004-08-17': 29},
                 {name: "Enos", '2004-08-17': 34}];
```

nggrid can not render the numbers correctly belonging to the date column, any suggestions?

Here is a Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/IEKMzs?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ng-grid does not support special characters in field name, so you need to change your field name to not have dashes.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/724).